# Circular function pointer question in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am trying to figure out how to declare a function that returns a pointer to a function that returns a function. It's a circular problem and I don't know if this can be done in c. This is an illustrative example of what I'm trying to do (it does not work):

```
typedef (*)(void) (*fp)(void);

fp funkA(void) {
    return funkB;
}

fp funkB(void) {
    return funkA;
}
```

Comment: "a pointer to a function that returns a function" - what's the signature of this last function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create completely circular types like this in C, you must use a `struct` (or `union`).  In C99:

```
typedef struct fpc {
    struct fpc (*fp)(void);
} fpc;

fpc funkB(void);

fpc funkA(void) {
    return (fpc){ funkB };
}

fpc funkB(void) {
    return (fpc){ funkA };
}
```

In C89, you don't have compound literals, so you must do:

```
fpc funkA(void) {
    fpc rv = { funkB };
    return rv;
}

fpc funkB(void) {
    fpc rv = { funkA };
    return rv;    
}
```

Comment: i can't experiment it now, but why shouldn't the OP solution, adding only the prototype for funkB as you did, work? (the other way: why do we need to wrap the pointer?)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Because the only kinds of types that can be defined to reference themselves are `struct` and `union` (you would need a *"pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning..."* - it's a snake trying to swallow its own tail).

Comment: I've just tested it with gcc, I needed casting to silent a warning I've not investigated yet deeply, but it worked... I am adding an answer, just for reference and analysis

Comment: @ShinTakezou: By using casting, you are not declaring such a type; you are avoiding the need to declare the type (but sacrificing type-safety in the process).

Comment: got it I had forgot a void * in the typedef :)

Comment: This worked. And I've learned that the compiler I'm using is only C89 compliant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
void (*(*f())())()
```

I always find [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) worthy and useful for such tasks. Query for the above was

```
declare f as function returning pointer to function returning pointer to function returning void
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning cdecl. That tool is massively helpful for stuff like this.

Comment: You can't use this to create a function that can return a pointer to itself, which is the circular reference that the OP seems to be after.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that cdecl. However trying a few different examples it seems that ultimately an actual value needs to be returned. I am looking for a way to just return a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
typedef void (*rfp)(void);
typedef rfp (*fp)(void);
```

This is not fully circular, but is very simple and could be ok for you.

A complete solution can be found on "[Guru of the Week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm)" with full explanation, and is this:

```
 struct FuncPtr_;
 typedef FuncPtr_ (*FuncPtr)();
 struct FuncPtr_
 {
     FuncPtr_( FuncPtr pp ) : p( pp ) { }
     operator FuncPtr() { return p; }
     FuncPtr p;
 };


 FuncPtr_ f() { return f; } // natural return syntax
 int main()
 {
    FuncPtr p = f();  // natural usage syntax
    p();
 }
```

Not so simple, but correct and portable...

Comment: @caf: you are right, I knew that well upfront. still, lacking a better solution... now, please, check the full solution I found on GOTW...

Comment: The GOTW answer is C++ and is definitely not portable C.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, which avoid indeed the circular problem, and so it is wrong in the context (and needs casting); though, if you don't need to be really circular nor strict, it works

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef void *(*fp)(void);

fp funcB(void);

fp funcA(void)
{
  printf("funcA %p\n", funcB);
  return (fp)funcB;
}

fp funcB(void)
{
  printf("func B %p\n", funcA);
  return (fp)funcA;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%p %p\n", funcA, funcB);
  printf("%p %p\n", funcA(), funcB()); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It won't be natural when you use type casting~ Logically it's not circular, although it can work.

Comment: Apart from the nonportability, you can't use the return values of the functions to call through, without using another cast.

Comment: See caf's answer, you can call `(*(((*((funkA()).fp))()).fp))();` to call `funkA()` if you like... no casting in it.

Comment: yes, you need to know the pointer you have is a "fp"; though I find it more practical than other solution; at least I would sacrifice type check if I would need such a thing for real. Likely not so good, but not too much shame I hope

Comment: @Stan: You don't need to explicitly dereference function pointers with `*`, so you can actually just do `funkA().fp().fp()`